# Initial keyboard on lowercase

Tags: android, input, keyboard, lowercase

When I click on a InputText, the first letter of the keyboard begins on uppercase. As I am entering an e-mail, the ideal would always be lowercase. Is possible set this programatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your XML file, you can use [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType). to set the field is a email input type.

Programmatically, you can do that with [setInputType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29)

You can specify that `myEditText` is an email field in your XML file :

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Or programmatically:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`TextView.setInputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) and [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).