# How to set Initial virtual keyboard as Lowercase (Android)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, shift

I have problem with HTC Sensation 4G (4.0.3).
I don't know why the Shift key on my virtual keyboard won't work for first time. But it'll work after I open virtual keyboard on other apps.
So, here's the flow :

1. **Open my app**
2. **Open virtual keyboard**, notice that my **initial case is Capital Case**.
3. **Press SHIFT**, notice that **SHIFT key doesn't work**. My keyboard still on Caps Case.
4. **Open another apps** (such as Play Store or Chrome) and **open it's virtual keyboard**
5. **Open my app**
6. **Open virtual keyboard**, notice that **virtual keyboard now is Lower Case**
7. Press SHIFT, and **SHIFT key works properly**

*At the beginning I thought that if I close my app and reopen it*, the issue will fixed. But I've tried to force close my app and open it. But the issue still happen (like I described  before) and I need to do those *"open another apps vKeyboard"* in order to make my SHIFT key working.

So **I think the solution is to make my virtual keyboard Lower Case on first show**.
Anyone know how to do it?

PS : *This only happen on HTC Sensation 4G with fw 4.0.3.*

I've read this : [Initial keyboard on lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430319/initial-keyboard-on-lowercase)

But it won't work on my case.

Anyone can help?

many thanks
-sb

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file, you can use android:inputType. to set the field is a email input type.

Programmatically, you can do that with setInputType()

You can specify that myEditText is an email field in your XML file :

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Or programmatically:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: Well, it's not working for me my case, dunno why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430319/initial-keyboard-on-lowercase