# Android keyboard - start lowercase

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, lowercase

Is it possible to start android keyboard with lowercase when I click on EditText?
Basically, what I want is to lowercase the first letter in EditText, but also to give user an possibility to make it uppercase if he want...

(EditText input is and must be multiline text)

**EDIT:**

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_str"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/enter_txt_here"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_card_selector"
                android:ellipsize="start" />
```

**EDIT2**
I think this is not possible when text must be multiline...

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is possible. Try researching the EditText [Input Types](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html).

For example you force the keyboard default state as lower case by simply:

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Or if you want to force capitalization for every sentense:

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

You can find a whole list types [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).

Comment: Try adding the InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS flag also.

Comment: What SDK version are you testing on?

Comment: Android 2.3.3 (SDK 10)

Comment: You can just add these flags in the XML, also you have maxLines=1 which would prevent multiline.

Comment: 'The attribute maxLines corresponds to the maximum height of the EditText, it controls the outer boundaries and not inner text lines'.

Answer (score 2):

Using xml you can force keyboard to make lowercase

```
android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
```

Answer (score 1):

As this page says:
[Initial keyboard on lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430319/initial-keyboard-on-lowercase)

Set input type to email addres:

```
Text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
text.setInputType(text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

or

```
text.setInputType(text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Did not work for me. What actually did it was this:

```
text.setInputType(inputEditText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); // forced capitalization
text.setInputType(inputEditText.getInputType() & ~ InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); // negate the flag
```

Comment: Did not work, at least in regards to making all text enter in lowercase.

Comment: This is actually to have the keyboard to initially use lower case.

Comment: Yeah. I need to have all characters converted to lower case.

Comment: Then you need to use filters, with them you can operate on the user input and modify it