# How to start text in input field with lowercase on Android?

Tags: android, html

I have [this webpage](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.html) and I have this textarea

```
<textarea class="clipboard"></textarea>
```

that I use to for mobile entry, and when I type something it always start for uppercase letter (the keyboard is in uppercase mode for first letter) how can I disable this feature?

It's fix when I add `left: -9999999px` but then the page don't scroll with the input.

Comment: check this answer i will start the keyboard in lower case [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961585/android-keyboard-start-lowercase)

Comment: @Dayvon it's about native app and I need solution for a webpage.

Comment: check this now it will help you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322314/convert-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase-and-first-uppercase-in-sentence-using-css)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `autocomplete`, `autocapitalize`, `autocorrect` and `spellcheck` attributes:

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Works on Chrome Dev (latest) and Android 5.1.1 with Google Keyboard and AOSP Keyboard. Doesn't work with SwiftKey Neural (which is in Alpha BTW).

Comment: Does this work for `input[type=text]` ?