# Input [text] Lowercase by default but can shift to Uppercase

Tags: javascript, php, html

Given

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Username'>
```

When I type on this input field, it is **Uppercase by default** in the android keyboard but I want to make **Lowercase the default** so users won't take time to click on the shift button.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to start text in input field with lowercase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728075/how-to-start-text-in-input-field-with-lowercase-on-android)

Comment: You can use autocapitalize="off" in your input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing `<input type="text" autocapitalize="none">`

It should work! :)

Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize